# Partially ordered set Question : $R$ relation on $\mathbb {N}$ iff $n\in \{1,5,5^{2},\dots,5^{k}\}$ , $x=n\cdot y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I`m trying to prove that this relation is partially ordered set:

$R$ relation on $\mathbb {N}$ iff $n\in \{1,5,5^{2},\dots,5^{k}\}$ and $x=n \cdot y$

the condition for partially ordered set are:

1. if for all $a \in A$(the functions set) implies $(a,a)\in R
       \rightarrow$ Reflexivity
2. for all $(a,b) \in R , (b,a) \in R \rightarrow a=b $ i.e. Anti - Symmetry
3. if for all $(a,b) \in R $ and $(b,c) \in R \rightarrow (a,c)\in R $ Transitivity

so for (1.) what I did is $xRx \rightarrow x=5^{0}x$ and $x\in \mathbb{N}$
for (2.) $(x,y)\in R \wedge (y,x)\in R \rightarrow x=n\cdot y$ and $ y=n\cdot x$
we get $y=n\cdot n\cdot y$ because $n\in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow n=1$ then we get the anti symmetry, what I did is right? or there is another way to prove it?
what about transitivity?
I would like to get some advice
Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Correction: you're trying to prove that $R$ is a partial order, not that it is a poset. What is the definition of $R$? I can't understand it.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense: a relation on $\Bbb N$ is a set of **ordered pairs** of natural numbers. (Also, I suspect that you mean $5^2$ in both places that you have $5^1$, since $5$ is already $5^1$.)

Comment: Did you mean $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\ \mathcal{R}\ y \stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff} \exists k \in \mathbb{N}.\ x = 5^k y$?

Comment: I added $x=n\cdot y$ and fix $5,\dots,5^{2}$.. thanks.

Comment: @dtldarek its $x=n\cdot y $ and $n\in \{\dots\}$ so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of reflexivity is fine.

Your proof of antisymmetry is not, though the basic idea is there. If $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ and $\langle y,x\rangle\in R$, then there are $k,\ell\ge 0$ such that $x=5^ky$ and $y=5^\ell x$, but $k$ and $\ell$ certainly don’t have to be the same. (If you prefer, there are $m,n\in\{1,5,5^2,\ldots\}$ such that $x=my$ and $y=nx$, but you can’t assume that $m=n$.) It follows that $x=5^ky=5^k(5^\ell x)=5^{k+\ell}x$. Clearly this implies that $5^{k+\ell}=1$, and since $k+\ell\ge 0$, we must have $k=\ell=0$ and $x=y$.

For transitivity you can use the same kind of calculation that I used in the previous paragraph. If $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ and $\langle y,z\rangle\in R$, then there are integers $k,\ell\ge 0$ such that $x=5^ky$ and $y=5^\ell z$. Now just combine these two equations to express $x$ in terms of $z$.

Comment: but how I can assume that $k+l=0$?

Comment: @Ofir: You know that $5^{k+\ell}=1$, right? So what does that force $k+\ell$ to be?

Comment: I dont, I need to set it to be 1? because I need to assume that $k=l$?

Comment: @Ofir: We have $x=5^{k+\ell}x$, where $x\ne 0$. Therefore $5^{k+\ell}$ must be $1$, right? And that implies that $k+\ell=0$.

Comment: Ah I see now, Thanks!

Comment: @Ofir: You’re welcome!

Comment: can you tell me what are the maximal and minimal terms here? nad if R is linear relation?

Comment: @Ofir: If $x\mathbin{R} y$, then either $x=y$, or $x$ is a multiple of $5$. Thus, if $x$ is a positive integer that is not a multiple of $5$, the only $y$ such that $x\mathbin{R}y$ is $x$ itself, and $x$ is therefore a maximal element. There are no minimal elements: show that if $x$ is any positive integer, $5x\mathbin{R}x$ and $5x\ne x$.

Comment: so for maximal there is 2 options, and for minimal I didnt understand it.

Comment: @Ofir: No, there are infinitely many maximal elements; some of them are $1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11$, and $12$. A positive integer $y$ is minimal if there is no $x\ne y$ such that $x\mathbin{R}y$. But there is **always** an $x\ne y$ such that $x\mathbin{R}y$: just let $x=5y$.